# Journey builder action/splits are based on user engagements taken place at CloudPages

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder

I what to create Journey that its actions/splits are based on user engagements taken place at my landing page (CloudPages).

For example, when a user clicked on button or link or even if user had only arrived at our landing page.
How can this task be solved?

Can I create a click event (or other) using AMPScript?
because if so, I could write that event to a DE and then address it from  my Journey(s)

Answer (score 0):

As AMPscript is interpreted on the server side you cannot directly track clicks or similar interaction via AMPscript.

However, you could create client side JavaScript code, that initiates a background request to a separate "processing" CloudPage. That processing page writes the interactions to a data extension. In the decision split you can then check the data contained in the cloud page's data extension.

**Useful documentation to implement this solution:**

- [jquery.post documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)
- [RequestParameter AMPscript function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/requestparameter.htm)
- [UpsertDE AMPscript function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/upsertde.htm)
- [InsertDE AMPscript function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/insertde.htm)